# Generating random conversions

Tags: conditionals, random-numbers

I am working on a system to randomly generate some exercises on unit conversion.
The students get a exercise like

> 27.89 mm = ...... hm

I achieved this whit the use of a random value generator and the `ifthen` package. But something is going wrong whit the spacing of this package.

This is the code I use whit one table of how it should be and one table that is randomly generated:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\randFloat}{
    \reinitrand[first=0, last=100, counter=var]
    \rand\arabic{var}.\rand\arabic{var}
    }
\newcommand{\randGrooth}{
    \reinitrand[first=1,last=7,counter = grooth]
    \rand
    \ifthenelse{\arabic{grooth} = 1}{mm}{
        \reinitrand[first=1,last=6,counter = test]
        \rand
        \ifthenelse{\arabic{test} = 1}{cm}{
            \reinitrand[first=1,last=5,counter = test]
            \rand
            \ifthenelse{\arabic{test} = 1}{dm}{
                \reinitrand[first=1,last=4,counter = test]
                \rand
                \ifthenelse{\arabic{test} = 1}{m}{
                    \reinitrand[first=1,last=3,counter = test]
                    \rand
                    \ifthenelse{\arabic{test} = 1}{dam}{
                        \reinitrand[first=1,last=2,counter = test]
                        \rand
                        \ifthenelse{\arabic{test} = 1}{hm}{km}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lcg}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
44.36 mm =& \hspace*{10 ex} m\\
56.28 dm=& \hspace*{10 ex} km
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\randFloat \randGrooth =& \hspace*{10 ex} \randGrooth\\
\randFloat \randGrooth =& \hspace*{10 ex} \randGrooth  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have umpteen end-of-lines that generate spaces in the output in the definition of `\randGrooth`; just three in the definition of `\randFloat`.

Comment: I'm afraid that also `lcg` adds several spurious spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses `pdftex` primitives, so it needs `pdflatex` to run.
The units are typeset with `siunitx` package, they are organized 
into an array by means of `\csname`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{round-mode = places,round-precision = 2}
%
\pdfsetrandomseed12345 %
%
\newcommand{\randFloat}{\pdfuniformdeviate100\expandafter.\pdfuniformdeviate100 }
%
\expandafter\def\csname0\endcsname{\si{\milli\metre}}
\expandafter\def\csname1\endcsname{\si{\centi\metre}}
\expandafter\def\csname2\endcsname{\si{\deci\metre}}
\expandafter\def\csname3\endcsname{\si{\metre}}
\expandafter\def\csname4\endcsname{\si{\deca\metre}}
\expandafter\def\csname5\endcsname{\si{\hecto\metre}}
\expandafter\def\csname6\endcsname{\si{\kilo\metre}}
%
\newcounter{ucount}
\newcommand{\incUcount}{%
\addtocounter{ucount}{\pdfuniformdeviate6 }%
\ifnum\arabic{ucount}>6 \addtocounter{ucount}{-7}\fi %
\expandafter\csname\arabic{ucount}\endcsname}

\newcommand{\randGrooth}{%
\incUcount\stepcounter{ucount} &= \hspace*{6 em}\incUcount\setcounter{ucount}{0}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{Sll}
\randFloat & \randGrooth \\ 
\randFloat & \randGrooth \\ 
\randFloat & \randGrooth \\ 
\randFloat & \randGrooth \\ 
\randFloat & \randGrooth \\ 
\randFloat & \randGrooth \\ 
\randFloat & \randGrooth \\ 
\randFloat & \randGrooth \\ 
\randFloat & \randGrooth \\ 
\randFloat & \randGrooth    
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I would use `\ifcase` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[first=1,last=7,counter=grooth]{lcg}

\newcommand\randFloat{{%
    \reinitrand[first=0, last=100, counter=var]
    \rand\arabic{var}.\rand\arabic{var}}}

\rand\gdef\OldRand{\thegrooth}

\newcommand\randGrooth{%
    \rand\ifnum\thegrooth=\OldRand \rand \fi
    \ifcase\thegrooth mm  % 0
      \or mm              % 1
      \or cm              % 2
      \or dm              % 3
      \or m               % 4
      \or dam             % 5
      \or hm              % 6
      \or km              % 7
    \fi
    \gdef\OldRand{\thegrooth}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
44.36\,mm =& \hspace*{10 ex} m\\
56.28\,dm=& \hspace*{10 ex} km
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\randFloat\,\randGrooth =& \hspace*{10 ex} \randGrooth\\
\randFloat\,\randGrooth =& \hspace*{10 ex} \randGrooth  
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\randFloat\,\randGrooth =& \hspace*{10 ex} \randGrooth\\
\randFloat\,\randGrooth =& \hspace*{10 ex} \randGrooth  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Herbert, I see that your solution works but can you give some more info on the lines '\rand\gdef\OldRand{\thegrooth}' and '\rand\ifnum\thegrooth=\OldRand \rand \fi'? I don't understand how they work.

Comment: I do not allow the same dimension for one line .If it is the same, then I run `\rand` again.If this is no problem for you, you can delete the `\fnum ...` part